# jakarta.json.stream.JsonParsingException when retrieving data from Elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

for some time now I have been trying to incorporate the Elastic Java 8.10 client into my code, I have a big ELK stack with a lot of data. I am trying to fetch continuously data from it, but I am encountering some inconsistent behavior.

My code is following the Elastic tutorial on their website and I have a simple function to get the data:

```java
/**
     * Method for querying a search in ELK using search_after.
     * @param search_size
     * @param index
     * @param sort_options
     * @param field
     * @param value
     * @return SearchResponse
     * @throws IOException on failed search
     */
    public final SearchResponse<JsonData> querySearch(final int search_size,
            final String index, final List<SortOptions> sort_options,
            final List<FieldValue> search_after, final String field,
            final String value) throws IOException {
        SearchResponse<JsonData> result = this.el_client.search(s -> s
            .index(index)
            .size(search_size)
            .sort(sort_options)
            .query(q -> q
                .term(t -> t
                    .field(field)
                    .value(v -> v.stringValue(value))
                )),
            JsonData.class);

        return result;
    }
```

The strange thing is that it works fine for some time, but then I always receive the following error:

```
Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.search.Hit: jakarta.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in name
```

it is inconsistent as it happens at random entries retrieved from Elasticsearch, I looked the previous entries that were retrieved and it is never the same time window (i am using the @timestamp field to cross-reference which entries might provoke the error)

Here is the stack trace:

```
 co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException: Error deserializing co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.search.Hit: jakarta.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in name
  at [Source: (org.apache.http.nio.entity.ContentInputStream); line: 1, column: 176305] (JSON path: hits.hits[55]._source) (line no=1, column no=176305, offset=-1)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException.from0(JsonpMappingException.java:134)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpMappingException.from(JsonpMappingException.java:121)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:218)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:148)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectBuilderDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectBuilderDeserializer.java:85)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializerBase$ArrayDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializerBase.java:318)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializerBase$ArrayDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializerBase.java:280)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:77)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer$FieldObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:78)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:192)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:148)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:77)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectBuilderDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectBuilderDeserializer.java:79)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer$FieldObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:78)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:192)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:148)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:77)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectBuilderDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectBuilderDeserializer.java:79)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.DelegatingDeserializer$SameType.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:43)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.DelegatingDeserializer$SameType.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:43)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.endpoints.EndpointWithResponseMapperAttr$1.deserialize(EndpointWithResponseMapperAttr.java:56)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.decodeResponse(RestClientTransport.java:377)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:347)
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:154)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1887)
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1904)
    at netrank.ElasticSourceClient.querySearch(ElasticSourceClient.java:190)
    at netrank.datasource.ElasticSource.run(ElasticSource.java:309)
    at be.cylab.mark.data.SourceWrapper.run(SourceWrapper.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
 Caused by: jakarta.json.stream.JsonParsingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in name
  at [Source: (org.apache.http.nio.entity.ContentInputStream); line: 1, column: 176305]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonUtils.convertException(JacksonUtils.java:36)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpParser.getJsonData(JacksonJsonpParser.java:435)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonData.from(JsonData.java:162)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonData.lambda$static$0(JsonData.java:169)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer$3.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:136)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:77)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.NamedDeserializer.deserialize(NamedDeserializer.java:64)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer$FieldObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeseri  at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectDeserializer.java:192)
    ... 27 more
 Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in name
  at [Source: (org.apache.http.nio.entity.ContentInputStream); line: 1, column: 176305]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase._throwUnquotedSpace(ParserBase.java:1046)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseEscapedName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1931)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseLongName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1872)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1810)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1767)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer._copyBufferContents(TokenBuffer.java:1155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer.copyCurrentStructure(TokenBuffer.java:1137)
    at co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpParser.getJsonData(JacksonJsonpParser.java:432)
    ... 34 more
```

At this point I have the feeling that the error is not from my code, but how the Elastic API sends the data and then the transformation from the raw JSON to JsonData. I tried using Object instead, but the same thing happens.
Is there a way to sanitize the JSON at the moment of fetching it or any way to correct this strange behavior?

**Small Update:**

I added a throw/catch line in the querySearch method to print the request send to ELK as output so I can check afterwards in the Kibana Developer Console to see the output and if there are errors in it.

Strangely, after I lowered the search_size (how many entries are fetched at once) from 100 to 50, I have no more Parsing errors. I wonder if the problem was the amount of lines retrieved and there being some artificial errors in them because of it.